# wordpress - displaying pages by specific ID order

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am tyring to do a fancy slider with pages. I am using bxslider and this works, but ordering pages by IDs in specific order doesn't work.

I have this. Can someone help me? Thanks!

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'parent' => 767,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'ID', 
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'include' => array(856, 771, 842, 866, 848, 809, 979, 860, 852, 870),
  ); 

  $posts = get_pages($args);  
?>
<ul class="bxslider"> 
<?php
  foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
  <li class="slide" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>">
      <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'small-thumb'); ?>
      <div class="title"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></div>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </li>
<?php
  endforeach;
?>
</ul> 
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by specific order?? possible values for order are ASC and DESC if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: What is the logic of the order ?

Comment: I have list of this pages on other page and I have it displayed by page order attribute? (I manualy added numbers in admin), but on homepage I need two pages switched. My client want to have it like that.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress - displaying pages by specific ID order

```
  <?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'parent' => 767,
        'post__in' => array(856, 771, 842, 866, 848, 809, 979, 860, 852, 870),
        'orderby' => 'post__in', 
        'order'   => 'ASC'
      ); 

      $posts = get_pages($args);  
    ?>
    <ul class="bxslider"> 
    <?php
      foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
      <li class="slide" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>">
          <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'small-thumb'); ?>
          <div class="title"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></div>
          <span></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    <?php
      endforeach;
    ?>
    </ul> 
    <?php 
    //endif; 
    wp_reset_query(); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the codex for the function you are using, namely - get_pages:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

You need to include 'sort_column' => 'ID'.
An example using your code:

```
$children = get_pages( array(
    'child_of'    => $post->post_parent,
    'sort_column' => 'ID'
) );
```